# call an R Script from an other script

Tags: r, rscript

I want to clean my R code, therefore i want to write several RScript's and call the Functions there, but i have no idea how to do this.

For example, I have the following call in my Main Class:

```
G = function(x) {
    return(-exp(-1i * x) * Conj(H(x+pi)) ) 
}
```

and the function H is written in an other R script as follows

```
H = function(x) {
    return (exp(-1i * x / 2) * cos(x / 2) )
}
```

Both RScripts are in the same Project but my Main Class doesen't recognize the function H.

Where is my error?

Thanks in anticipation

Matthias

Comment: Function `G` is dependent on function `H`.  Did you define `H` before you defined `G`?

Comment: Hi, the code is working and the function H was defined before G, but now i want to exclude the function H in an other Rscript to clean my code, therefore it is not longer recognized. My qestion is not how to get access to a function in an other RScript.

Comment: How about `rm(list=c("H"))`?  Wouldn't that remove `H` from your environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call an RScript from another script, you need to `source` it at the beginning:

```
source("H.R")
# H is now available
G = function(x) {
     return(-exp(-1i * x) * Conj(H(x+pi)) ) 
}
```

If you want to clean up your functions, you can also build a package containing all your functions.

A little bit more of work, but definitely worth the effort!

Comment: Hi Colin FAY and thanks for your answer. I created a package already and in this package is my Main and the function H. I also added source("H.R") but i get the message:  "cannot open file 'H.R': No such file or directory"

Comment: I found my error, i have to add the whole path. Thank you for your help.